# How to display datetime field with a certain format

Tags: django, django-views, jinja2

I have a `datetime` field column where I use in my detail view template. I show this in my HTML page as: `{{ post.created_at }}` and the output is: `July 15, 2018, 7:03 p.m` Which is way verbose than I need it to be.

I would like the following:

- If I posted a post 59 minutes ago, it should display as `59m`
- If I posted a post 23 hours ago, it should display as `23h`
- If I posted a post 6 days ago, it should display as `6d`
- Now anything that exceeds a week's time, should be displayed as day, month, year. In the example we have above it should be: `15 Jul 18` with no time.

Is there a way to accomplish this in the HTML page using Jinja?

Comment: Looks like `naturaltime` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime), but it will not fall back to a the day notation after a week.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hmm, this is a bit verbose as well. `16 Feb 2007 13:31:29 becomes 1 day, 2 hours ago.` should only be `1 day` do you know if there is a way to make it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom filter for this. I use one like the following. It does not format exactly according to your spec, but you will get the idea:

`{{ value|format_date_human(locale='en') }}`

```
def format_date_human(to_format, locale='en', timezoneinfo='Asia/Calcutta'):
    tzinfo = timezone(timezoneinfo)
    now = datetime.now()
    #logging.info('delta: %s', str((now - to_format).days))
    #logging.info('delta2: %s', str((datetime.date(now)-datetime.date(to_format)).days))

    if datetime.date(to_format) == datetime.date(now):
        date_str = _('Today')
    elif (now - to_format).days == 1:
        date_str = _('Yesterday')
    else:
        month = MONTHS[to_format.month - 1]
        date_str = '{0} {1}'.format(to_format.day, _(month))
    time_str = format_time(to_format, 'H:mm', tzinfo=tzinfo, locale=locale)
    return "{0}".format(date_str, time_str)
```

Comment: can you add import statement, it will be helpfull